# how to find a row index of second sheet using that cell value in first sheet in excel in java

Tags: java

I'm Looking for help with a fairly basic excel in java to read a value in a cell on one Excel sheet and then find that value in a second sheet and i want to return that row number

To break it down...

Read the value of a given cell in sheet_1 (this will be an ID number)
Go to sheet_2, find the ID number in column_a
return that row number in which that cell value belongs
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use [Apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/index.html)

here's an [example](http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-read-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi)